# What is this constellation?

Tags: constellations

Every night I see this constellation from my window but I can't identify it. What is this constellation called? Also, it would be helpful if you could clarify on the other stars as well.

Actual photo:

[image: Actual photo]

Pattern:

[image: Pattern]

Comment: What research did you take to try to answer this yourself? What resources have you already consulted?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can see the constellation Orion on this photo:

[image]
(Screenshot from [Stellarium](http://stellarium.org/))

Aligning the original photo with this screenshot, I found the highlighted stars to be the following:

[image]

Answer (score 9):

The constellation in the lower right is Orion, characterized by its famous "belt" of 3 stars. The two stars in the top center and top right belong to Taurus, the latter being Aldebaran. I am not sure about the stars to the left, it seems like it's part of Gemini.

Answer (score 5):

What you have shown is almost the complete ["Winter Hexagon"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winter_Hexagon), an [asterism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asterism_(astronomy)) composed of Rigel, Aldebaran, Capella, Pollux, Procyon, and Sirius.

[image]

Capella and Sirius are slightly out of frame in your picture:

[image]

If you have the chance, you might want to look at the [position marked by the green dot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orion_Nebula), either with a telescope or binoculars.